# combine multiple rows into a single row with comma

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I would like to combine rows as below.

This is the original data:

[image: This is the original data]

the expected result as:

[image: the expected result as]

can someone help me how to do it?
I try to copy and paste my data, I can't do it here.
Thanks

Comment: WITH RECURSIVE query and GROUP_CONCAT in mariadb.

Comment: Replace the images with actual data example, and show what you've tried so far.   Also, indicate which SQL product you are using

Comment: I am using SQL ver18. I have been searched but I can't find the query I can use it.

Comment: SQL ver18 doesn't indicate what database you are using.

Comment: "SQL" is a query language used by all relational database. Are you using PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, DB2 ....